# Custom footer menu appear after clicking floating button

Tags: android, material-design

How I can apply the animation of material design to display a custom footer menu after clicking on the floating button?

[Components – Buttons: Floating Action Button](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-behavior)

Comment: Can you post a, little bit more detail about what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: i need a button that disapear when is clicked, then it triggers another element, something like a panel or footer, that shows up with a centain animation

Comment: I found a possible solution using this https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3495 @war_Hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a class extends BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
public class FooterSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


    public static FooterSheetDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new FooterSheetDialogFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_al_dia, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Second: `

```
mFloatingButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.floatingButtonAlDia);`
        mFloatingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    BottomSheetDialogFragment bsdFragment = FooterSheetDialogFragment.newInstance();
                    bsdFragment.show(FragmentAlDia.this.getFragmentManager(), "BSDialog");
                }
            }
        );
```